# Find the solution of $ye^{-x/y}dx -xe^{-x/y}dy = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of $ye^{-x/y}dx -xe^{-x/y}dy = 0$

My approach : put x=vy $\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dy} =v +y \frac{dv}{dy}$

The equation becomes $\frac{vye^{-v}}{ye^{-v}} =v +y \frac{dv}{dy}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{ve^{-v}}{e^{-v}} =v +y \frac{dv}{dy}$

Please suggest whether this is the correct method and  if yes, how to proceed further, will be of great help. thanks

Comment: Something is amiss in this question as $e^{-x/y}$ cancels out and one gets a trivial equation  $ydx-xdy =0 $ whose solution is $y=Cx$..

Comment: There is no need to perform any substitution as $e^{-xy}\neq 0$. The solution is $y=Cx$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ye^{-x/y}dx -xe^{-x/y}dy = 0$$
$$\implies e^{-x/y}(ydx -xdy) = 0$$
$$\implies ydx -xdy = 0\qquad \text{as}\quad e^{-x/y}\ne 0$$
$$\implies \frac{ydx -xdy}{y^2}=0$$
Integrating, $$\frac{x}{y}=c\qquad \text{where $c$ is a constant}~.$$

Comment: This was already mentioned inside the comments. It appears that the OP might have made a mistake in the original question.

Comment: Then he has to modify his question in proper order.